# Images not shown in photos using adb push pictures to android 11 emulator?

Tags: android, android-11

Before android 11, I can use adb push images to `/sdcard/DCIM/` directory and use `am broadcast -a android.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE -d <file path>`, then images will show in gallery.

Now I find this approach doesn't work in android 11 emulator, images are pushed to devices, but they won't show without a restart.

Is there anyway I can transfer images from host to emulator and make them appear in photo gallery?

Comment: After some searching I only know that this MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE is deprecated in API 29:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE

The other thing I'm using to make files show is to run this SDScanner app but it takes time to go over all the existing files in the db:

Comment: The "SD Scanner" app above can be downloaded from F-Droid. Takes 50s to scan my phone, with a 10.5MB external.db. Could be faster if you have fewer files.

Comment: Hi @Aaron Shen did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: On my Android 13 device it works but it seems to work only for certain directories. For me it works if I put it in /sdcard/DCIM/Camera